# Function to Find Total Number of 4's in Each Column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

Is it possible to create a function to find the total number of 4's in each column in a dataframe. In each, I would also like to divide the total number of 4's in each column by the total number of values in the column to output a decimal.

Currently, this is what I have done. I first identify the specific column and then use value_counts to look only for the 4's in the column and divide by the total number of values in the column. This however, has to be done for each column. Can this be done in a function that can be applied to a series of columns or the dataframe all together?

```
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('ColumnA')]
df[cols] = (df['ColumnA'].value_counts()[4]/df['ColumnA'].count())
```

This is the dataframe I am working with:
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please add a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you just loop through cols? `for col in cols:` and then  do the manipulation

Comment: I do need a function as opposed to a loop so that I can re-use it for other dataframes. My issue is that right now, I am simply copying and pasting these lines for all the columns - which is not a good practice.

Comment: Do you want to ignore `nan` values in each column? For ColB, the result can be 0.375 if you keep NaN or 0.500 if you drop NaN.

Comment: Exactly, I want to ignore the NaN values in each column. My thought is that the function will first get rid of the NaN cells in each column and then find the total number of 4's in the column and then divide the total number of 4's by the total number of values in the column (excluding the nulls).

Answer (score 2):

To expand on my comment with a full code (though you do need to add an example dataset for us to provide a better solution):

```
# get the list of columns that you want to updated
cols_to_update = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
# loop through each column
for col in cols_to_update:
   df[col] = (df[col].value_counts()[4]/df[col].count())
```

If you necessarily need a func, use something like this:

```
def df_update(df, cols):
    # loop through each column
    for col in cols:
        df[col] = (df[col].value_counts()[4]/df[col].count())
    return df
```

Unless I've misunderstood, this should work for your use case given you have the list of columns to update

Comment: Thanks for this, this is very helpful - how would I apply this to my dataframe?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Also, you have not given us a dataframe!

Comment: Gotcha! I added a link to the mock data! Really what I want - is a function that first drops NaN cells in each column, then counts the number of 4's in each, divides the number of 4's by the total number of non-null responses to get a decimal value in each cell. Btw, thanks for your help - your explanations are very clear!

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use:

```
count = df.select_dtypes('number').eq(4).sum().div(len(df))
print(count)

# Output
ColA    0.500
ColB    0.375
ColC    0.375
ColD    0.375
ColE    0.250
ColF    1.000
ColG    0.125
dtype: float64
```

If you want to ignore `NaN`, do:

```
df1 = df.select_dtypes('number')
count = df1.eq(4).sum().div(df1.count())
print(count)

# Output
ColA    0.500000
ColB    0.500000
ColC    0.375000
ColD    0.500000
ColE    0.250000
ColF    1.000000
ColG    0.166667
dtype: float64
```

[Minimal Working Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
data  = {'ID': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
         'ColA': [4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1],
         'ColB': [3.0, 4.0, 2.0, 4.0, nan, 4.0, nan, 1.0],
         'ColC': [2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 4],
         'ColD': [4.0, 4.0, 4.0, nan, nan, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
         'ColE': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4],
         'ColF': [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
         'ColG': [3.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 2.0, nan, 1.0, nan],
         'Sex': ['M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(df)

# Output
  ID  ColA  ColB  ColC  ColD  ColE  ColF  ColG Sex
0  A     4   3.0     2   4.0     1     4   3.0   M
1  B     4   4.0     2   4.0     2     4   2.0   F
2  C     3   2.0     2   4.0     3     4   3.0   M
3  D     2   4.0     3   NaN     1     4   4.0   F
4  E     4   NaN     4   NaN     2     4   2.0   F
5  F     4   4.0     1   1.0     3     4   NaN   F
6  G     3   NaN     4   1.0     4     4   1.0   M
7  H     1   1.0     4   1.0     4     4   NaN   M
```